# GetManifestResourceStream returns NULL

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

This is a C# .NET 4.0 application:

I'm embedding a text file as a resource and then trying to display it in a dialog box:

```
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var resourceName = "MyProj.Help.txt";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(result, "MyProj", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
```

The solution is MyProjSolution and the executable is MyProj.exe. Help.txt is an embedded resource. However, the stream is null. I've tried MyProjSolution.Help.txt and MyProjSolution.MyProj.Help.txt but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Use ildasm.exe to look at the .mresource names in the assembly manifest.  Do avoid falling into this pit of misery, use Project + Properties, Resource tab instead.  So you can just use Properties.Resources.Help in your source code.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You can check that the resources are correctly embedded by using

```
//From the assembly where this code lives!
this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()

//or from the entry point to the application - there is a difference!
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

when debugging. This will list all the (fully qualified) names of all resources embedded in the assembly your code is written in.

See [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Simply copy the relevant name, and use that instead of whatever you have defined in the variable 'resourceName'.

Notes - the resource name is case sensitive, and if you have incorrectly embedded the resource file, it will not show up in the list returned by the call to GetManifestResourceNames(). Also - make sure you are reading the resource from the correct assembly (if multiple assemblies are used) - it's all too easy to get the resources from the currently executing assembly rather than from a referenced assembly.

**EDIT - .NET Core**
Please see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34482129/685341) for details on how to embed using .NET Core.

Retrieving the manifest info looks to be similar - just use `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` to get the a manifest from the assembly where the code is executing.

I haven't figured out how to do the equivalent of  `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` in .NET Core yet! if anyone knows - please let me know and I will update this answer.

Comment: That worked. ProjectName.Resources.Help.txt was the embedded resource name.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! If you feel that this post has answered your question, then please don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, so in .Net Standard it should be [ProjectName].[Namespace].[Resource]. I missing the project name. Thanks!

Comment: My issue was using GetExecutingAssembly() instead of GetEntryAssembly(). The resource I wanted was in the executable, but the function to load the resource lived in another, referenced project in the same solution.

Comment: I had same issue when I added the resource through the GUI. Then I read this post https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/saving-an-embedded-file-in-C-Sharp/. I add an existing item through VS, then use this name: "ConsoleApp1.myfile.txt" so it: "<namespace>.<filename>".

Answer (score 81):

I had a similar issue check first that the file is included in your project , then go to properties and set the build action of that file to Embedded Resource . this worked for me .

Comment: This helped me! I had some files added earlier that defaulted to embedded resource, then ones I added later that were set to "None". Visual Studio is so annoying at times. The worst part of this is that all of the XML files for resources have NO setting for build action. Should have the build action set there.

Comment: Remember to use the default namespace and path to resource. eg `DefatultNameSpace.Infrastructure.Help.txt`. Default namespace in your project properties page and `Infrastructure` would be the folder you file is in

Comment: This is what i wanted Cheers!

Answer (score 62):

The embedded file's **"Build Action"** property should be set as **"Embedded Resource"** to run the line, which is given below, properly:

```
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
```

Right click on the file, click the property and then set "Build Action" property as "Embedded Resource":

[image]

Comment: Exactly what was my issue. Thanks!

Comment: This was my problem. I added it using Resources.resx and it didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the cause of my null value.

http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2011/07/18/cs-getmanifestresourcestream-gotcha/

The `GetManifestResourceStream` method will always returns `NULL` if the resource ‘built action‘ property is not set to ‘embedded resource‘

After setting this property with all the needed files `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` starts returning the correct stream instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks again. This fixed my issue a month or two ago then I forgot about it and had the same issue and it fixed it again.

Comment: Thanks You save my day

Answer (score 11):

Just a warning.

I could not access my file as an embedded resource even though I specified that it was and even though it had that Build Action property. Wasted a lot of time banging my head. I embedded a csharp code file with .txt appended to its name (xxx.cs.txt). For some reason the GetManifestResourceNames() and GetManifestResourceStream() methods won't see a file with .cs in its name.

I renamed it simply xxx.txt and everything was fine.

Weird.

Comment: This has sapped too much time today! It will embed it if you use `Resource` but not `Embedded Resource`, which makes it even weirder... Removing `.cs.` from the name makes it work. Argh.

Comment: The problem is not that .cs. path/segment in files is recognized as C# file but rather as a CultureInfo.

Comment: It seems that with a double extension it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, thanks to Jay I found it was hyphens in the directory name.

`ProjectName.ResourceFolder.Sub-Directory` becomes `ProjectName.ResourceFolder.Sub_Directory` when you reference the resource stream.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was that the code looking for the resource was in a different project that the resource itself.

You can only access resources that are in the same project the code is. I thought I could put all my resources in the web page project, but I need images in the mail project too.

Hope this helps someone in the same situation I was.

I find really useful calling `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();`.

Comment: This is not true, at least since 2011: through both [Assembly.LoadFrom()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570201/2752308) and [typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717248/2752308) you can access resources that are in another project

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone else, Make sure `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` line is called from same assembly which has embedded resources.

Comment: Except if you call it from another project, and in this case you should use [Assembly.LoadFrom()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570201/2752308) or [typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717248/2752308) so you can access resources that are in another project...

Answer (score 2):

A simple and streamlined solution is to have this **base** class:

```
public class EmbededResourceReader
{
    protected string LoadString(string fileName)
    {
        return LoadString(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    protected string LoadString(string fileName, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var assembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
        var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{this.GetType().Namespace}.{fileName}");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream, encoding))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you add a resource, you create a reader C# class in the same folder:

[image]

where the reader class MyResource.cs is very simple:

```
public class MyResource : EmbededResourceReader
{
    public string LoadString() => LoadString($"{nameof(MyResource)}.txt");
}
```

So, each resource will have a "shadow" class that knows how to read it properly.

This is how you read the resource in your code:

```
var text = new MyResource().LoadString();
```

And as other answers suggested, do not forget to set "Embedded Resource" in the Build Action property of the resource file.

The advantage of this uniform solution is

1. less hassle with finding correct full name of the resource, especially when placed in nested folders
2. in case when folder is renamed OR Default Namespace in project settings is changed, the code will NOT break

Answer (score 0):

```
    First Unload the project and click on edit the project file. 

    Inside the project file make sure that the item you are fetching from the assembly is included inside <EmbeddedResource> tag.

    Eg: 

         <ItemGroup>
          <EmbeddedResource Include="Template\ForExampleFile.html" />
         </ItemGroup>


    The files I added into the project were just in Content tag but not in the EmbeddedResource as shown below by default. Hence the stream was returning null.
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Template\ForExampleFile.html" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unload your solution.Then edit project.Afterfind your folder and change like this:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="yourpath" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Although OP got **GetManifestResourceStream returning NULL** from resources in the same Assembly, some Answers suggested that when Resources are in another Project or Assembly they cannot be retrieved, and are a fair cause of GetManifestResourceStream returning NULL.

This is not true, at least since 2011; as I pointed in some comments elsewhere, [Assembly.LoadFrom()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570201/2752308) or [typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717248/2752308) do the trick and as a result you can access resources that are in another project.

I have a moderately complex example here to illustrate; this is my test setup:

[image]

Path to another project:

[image]

Captured here:

```
 var sharedXMLResource =
                "D:\\My Documents\\Consultório Impressos\\DB Pacientes\\Teste\\TestesVariados\\WinFormFramework\\Read_Embedded_XML_File_CS\\bin\\Debug\\Read_Embedded_XML_File_CS.exe";
```

And on Form1.cs from WinFormFramework I specify with

> Namespace.Folder.Resource

like that:

```
StreamReader reader = 
                new StreamReader(Assembly.LoadFrom(sharedXMLResource).GetManifestResourceStream("Read_Embedded_XML_File_CS.SharedResources.ContactList.xml") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
```

And the result displayed at textbox:
[image]

I spent several hours to get it right; for that, I had to use a lot these at Immediate Window:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(WinFormFramework.Program)).Location
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however, I stumbled through this and with the help of @Jay answer I was able to get this working.

I had to use the full filename to get this to work.

```
using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Project.Folder.appsettings.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the resource you are trying to use is available in the list of embedded resources by writing below ling of code in Application_Startup() of App.xaml, either you can print the array or check in debug mode:

```
string[] resources = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

If not available in the resources[], then go to folder and click on resource file(in my case test.wav) **Resources->test.wav->in Properties Build Action needs to be changed to Embedded Resource**.
[image]

Then try again, GetManifestResourceStream() should not return null now:

```
Stream ringback = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
                "MyProject.Resources.test.wav");
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to specify the path to your txt file in the `GetManifestResourceStream` parameter, or you could try sticking the txt file in the same directory as your executable. Hope that helps!