VS custom build step + embedded resource =?
In Visual Studio 2022 with C#/.NET, how can I have some files that are compiled by a custom build tool then have the output of that tool be included as embedded resources (e.g. Build Action: Embedded Resource) in the resulting assembly?
EDIT: I just ran across a way to do this (though it would be nice if there were a better way). It's possible to edit Visual Studio project files to refer to files that don't actually exist on disk (or not yet), and you can even set them to embedded resources. One way to do this would then be to create pre-build steps to invoke the compiler for each file, then use the project editing trick to include the output files as embedded resources. It works, though having to do two completely different things in completely different places for each file is not ideal; it would be really nice if there were a way to instead of specifying "embedded resource" you could specify "build with x then include as embedded resource".
Also, there is an issue with this approach, at least if your custom compiler is itself a project built in the solution. I'm not yet sure if it's inherent to MSBuild or if it only occurs with GitHub actions, but when you do this, pre-build steps of let's call it Project A can occur BEFORE Project B builds, even when Project B is set as a dependency of Project A. Obviously this causes the pre-build steps to fail because the compiler doesn't exist yet...

This question is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762368/embedded-resource-in-net-core-libraries
If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and whether the answers on that question are helpful for your problem.

@FeiXu These questions are not at all similar. I am asking how to compile a file with a custom tool and THEN add it as an embedded resource. It seems that linked question is very old and the answer in modern versions of .NET is simple. It is combining embedded resources (simple) with custom build tools that is not at all clear how to do.

@FeiXu Indeed when I said "e.g. Build Action: Embedded Resource" in my question that WAS the answer to the linked question, at least in modern versions of .NET.

What solutions have you tried by now? @Justin Olbrantz

Just yesterday I ran across a solution to the problem: apparently manually editing Visual Studio project files allows you to refer to files that don't exist initially, and even mark them as embedded resources. Thus a not very good solution would be to create pre-build steps to invoke the compiler, then use the manually edited project file trick to include the output as an embedded resource. While this works, it's far from ideal as it means you need to add two completely different things for every single file you want to build this way, so I wouldn't really call it an "answer".

Have you considered using MSBuild? MSBuild's built-in features can incorporate the steps you mentioned into the project file, which can reduce the complexity of manual configuration, such as using the BeforeTargets and AfterTargets properties to specify the target order:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2022
