# Visual Studio 2015 .NETCore class library copy folder to bin/Debug/net452

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have a .NET Core class library project `ClassLibrary1` created in Visual Studio 2015. In this class library project, I added a folder `NewFolder` that will be used by whichever project is referencing `ClassLibrary1`.

So for instance, I have a project called `ConsoleApplication1` that references `ClassLibrary1`. Every time I build `ConsoleApplication1`, `NewFolder` should be copied

**FROM**

`PROJECT_PATH\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\NewFolder`

**TO**

`PROJECT_PATH\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\NewFolder`

**UPDATE:**

I added the following to the `project.json` file of my `ClassLibrary1` project.

```
"buildOptions: {
    "copyToOuput": "NewFolder"
}"
```

It only copies the the folder to `PROJECT_PATH\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\NewFolder` but not to `PROJECT_PATH\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\NewFolder` every time I build `ConsoleApplication1`.

I have no idea how this should be done in .NET Core projects because this does not seem to be the behaviour for non .NET Core projects.

**UPDATE 2:**

In non .NET Core projects I simply add a script to the post-build events command line of `ClassLibrary1` and it automagically copies everything in the `ClassLibrary1/bin/Debug` including files and folders to `ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug`.

`xcopy "$(ProjectDir)NewFolder" "$(TargetDir)NewFolder" /E /Y`

Comment: updated my answer, this works, I checked...

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in non .NET Core is create a link to the folder/item in the project (your case `ConsoleApplication1` and then set it to be copied to output.

any way, this can't be done in .net core.

What you are doing is also wrong, the project.json of `ClassLibrary1` does not copy files to the output of `ConsoleApplication1` what you should do is add the following to your `project.json` of `ConsoleApplication1`

```
"copyToOutput": {

  "mappings": {
    "NewFolder/": {
      "include": "../ClassLibrary1/bin/Debug/net452/win7-x64/NewFolder/**"
    }
  }

}
```

`mappings` - defines the folders to copy to (`NewFolder`) (the `/` is apparently necessary)

`include` - Defines glob patterns and file paths to include for copying to build output.

#### UPDATE

you can embed your files using [buildOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34482129/3090249) and accessing it using

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: this works! however, it requires that I put the configuration in `ConsoleApplication1`. I was actually looking for a solution where the configuration is only written in `ClassLibrary1` like the behaviour in non .NET Core projects. Please see `UPDATE 2`. Im not sure if it is possible though

Comment: Looking at this https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2902 issue, there is a bug with `copyToOutput` that won't be fixed soon. The last comment suggests embedding your files in the dll, and accessing it accordingly