# Reading from a file in Xamarin.Android project

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to access a .pbf file from the MainActivity class in an Xamarin Android. I tried adding the file to a new Maps folder, I also tried adding it to the Assets and Resources folders.

I've tried setting them with different build actions. However this error is always generated... "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file"

```
using (var inputStream = 
   new FileInfo(@"Resources\ireland.osm.pbf").OpenRead())
{
...
}
```

How should the file be added to the project and accessed using FileInfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly what you probably want to do is use Assets and follow this [Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/)

Including files as your application doesnt work the same as if you were to access them directly on the file system. Now you wont be able to get `FileInfo` from the asset but you will be able to read them.

First place the `ireland.osm.pbf` file in the `Assets` directory. Next you must (and usually does it for you if you choose *Add Existing Item*) set the Build Action to `AndroidAsset`. This builds (packages) the file as part of the Android Package.

Next Assets are loaded (accessed) through the [`AssetManager`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.AssetManager/). Luckily this is available in the Activity Context through `this.Assets`.

To read the asset is quite simple.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("ireland.osm.pbf")))
{
    //do as you wish with the stream reader.
}
```

*Edit:*

From the comment.

> but i need the FileInfo to implement the PBFOsmStreamSource() as shown here link

I had a quick look at the source code for [`PBFOsmStreamSource()`](https://github.com/OsmSharp/core/blob/develop/src/OsmSharp/Streams/PBFOsmStreamSource.cs) and has the constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new source of PBF formated OSM data.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stream"></param>
public PBFOsmStreamSource(Stream stream)
{
    _stream = stream;
}
```

Now stream reader is *NOT* a `Stream` we need to convert it to a `Stream` however does have the property [`BaseStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.basestream(v=vs.110).aspx). Now given I dont have a test enviroment you should be able to call.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("ireland.osm.pbf")))
{
    //do as you wish with the stream reader.
    var pbfStreamSource = new PBFOsmStreamSource(sr.BaseStream);

}
```

**EDIT 2**

`StreamReader.BaseStream()` does not support the `Seek()` method. Reading further on the source for `PBFOsmStreamSource` shows.

```
private void Initialize()
{
    _stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    this.InitializePBFReader();
}
```

Which is why you are getting the `System.NotSupporte‌​dException` exception. Therefore you will need to construct a stream that supports the `Seek()` method. Fortunatly `MemoryStream` is capable of changing the position and supports the `Seek()` method.

Again, I do not have a test enviroment.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("ireland.osm.pbf")))
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sr.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
        var pbfStreamSource = new PBFOsmStreamSource(ms);
    }
}
```

**Final Edit**

After more review and looking at their samples I have written an example console application that uses `StreamReader` in the same fasion as you would on the mobile. Now I have tweaked this slightly so we can dispose of the `StreamReader` quickly as these files consume a large amount of memory and there is no need to keep both streams open at once.

```
using OsmSharp.Geo;
using OsmSharp.Osm.PBF.Streams;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample.GeometryStream
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static async Task Test()
        {

            await ToFile("http://files.itinero.tech/data/OSM/planet/europe/luxembourg-latest.osm.pbf", "test.pbf");

            var sr = new StreamReader("test.pbf");
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    sr.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //TODO: Handle exceptions
                }
                finally
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    sr.Dispose();
                }
                var pbfStreamSource = new PBFOsmStreamSource(ms);
            }
        }

        public static async Task ToFile(string url, string filename)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
                using (var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This allows me to access the file but i need the FileInfo to implement the PBFOsmStreamSource() as shown here [link](https://github.com/OsmSharp/ui/wiki/A-getting-started-example)

Comment: @Rani I have updated the response. Have a look at `BaseStream` property of `StreamReader`

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Got this error but it may be unrelated... _{System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
  at Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker.Seek (Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/InputStreamInvoker.cs:38 
  at OsmSharp.Osm.PBF.Streams.PBFOsmStreamSource.Initialize () [0x00001] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OsmSharp.Osm.Streams.Filters.OsmStreamFilterTagsFilter.Initialize () [0x00007] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OsmSharp.Osm.Streams.OsmStreamTarget.Pull ()_

Comment: Ok, so somewhere its trying to invoke the `Seek` method on the stream and the `BaseStream` probably doesnt support that. Therefore we need a different type of stream that does support `Seek`. One that comes to mind is `MemoryStream`. Again will update the response.

Comment: @Ruairi final edit posted. The solution should work properly for you. Cheers Nico

Comment: Yes great thanks @Nico. Also found another way of doing it using 'map.AddLayer(new LayerMBTile(OsmSharp.Android.UI.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFrom(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"OsmSharp.Android.UI.Sample.kempen.mbtiles"), "map")));' Details here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637830/getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null]