# Embedded resource won't work for some filenames?

Tags: vb.net

Okay - I'm confused.

If I have an embedded resource file called light.sms.txt, then it is not embedded, but if I change it to light.sms1.txt, then it is embeded ... emm .. why?

Here's what I do...

1. Create a new WinForm project
2. Add a text file called `light.sms.txt` and change build action to Embedded resource
3. Paste this code in Form1 ...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Static embededResources As String() = GetType(Form1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
    MsgBox(embededResources.Length.ToString)
End Sub
```

4. Run the app - the result is 3
5. Change the embbeded filename to `light.sms1.txt`
6. Run the app - the result is now 4

Why doesn't "light.sms.txt" get embedded?

Comment: I have tried your code and first it did not show up. But after **Cleaning** and **Building** it worked with both filenames.

Comment: I've tried cleaning and rebuild - still doesn't show up. This is wierd.

Comment: One thing confirmed, only `.sms` tag names aren't showing up. I've tried @CodePope's trick, that didn't work. I've tried creating a new project and **this time**, I created `new.txt` and assigned to **Embedded resource**, it showed up, but as soon as I renamed it to `light.sms.txt`, it failed. Lastly when I replaced `.sms` to `-sms` and `.smss` (for testing), it worked. It's a weird error. I'm recommending you to rename the file instead.

Comment: It's a problem to rename files - I'm adding 7,000+ files (Fontawesome) and it woul be a nightmare to manage renaming files that does not work.

Comment: I have observed similar behavior in the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637830/getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null#answer-27851799

Comment: Have you checked on how the file is represented in the .vbp file?  It might be that Visual Studio is getting confused, but you can hand-edit the .vbp file to fix the problem.  You can right-click on the project, choose "Unload", then right-click again, and choose "Edit" to load it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim getName As String

    Static embededResources As String() = GetType(Form1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
    For Each index In embededResources
        getName += index + vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox(getName)
End Sub
```

You'll get to know that when the filename is `light.sms.txt` as embedded resources, it doesn't adds it to the `embeddedResources` array. But when you changes the filename, it shows up and counts +1 value.

The above code's output (before name change vs. after name change):

[image: Before]      [image: After]

That's the reason of it. You may replace the file name to `light-sms.txt` instead.

Comment: @MojoDK I'm not sure about that, you may remove the "sms" tag. I've just seen it works perfect without `sms`. Better replace the `light.sms.txt` to `light-sms.txt`